# On transit Dubai - passport validity

Tags: transit, passports, dubai, portuguese-citizens

Hi I will be on transit in Dubai, travelling from Brisbane to Lisbon on the 12 December with my wife and 5 year old son. We arrive at Dubai on the 12 December 2016 at 13:00 and leave the next day to Lisbon at 6:30. Emirates airline will provide accommodation. We all have Portuguese passports.

Do we require visa? My son passport will expire on 18 of April 2017, is it still valid?

Answer (score 5):

You don't require a [visa](http://www.emirates.com/uk/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx) in advance (unless the rules change meanwhile!) and the imminent [expiry](http://www.emirates.com/uk/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/find_visa_requirements.aspx) of your son's passport is not an issue. To enter Dubai the passport needs to have 3 months left from the arrival date